# is it possible to show image histogram in eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, image, histogram

is there any possible function that i can use to show image histogram in eclipse ?.

if there is not. could you explain to me the reason ?. You can just share your opinion. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Why would an IDE contain such functionality? You wouldn't expect to compile code in Photoshop, would you? However, since you can write plugins for eclipse, in theory it would be possible to have any such functionality you want. I doubt anyone's written a plugin like that already though.